# «Воробьишко» — как склонять?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, существительные

У Горького есть детский рассказ "Воробьишк**о**". Как его [название] склонять?
Словарь предлагает только слово "воробьишк**а**".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Форма "воробьишко" устарела. 
Склонялась она по образцу существительных на -а/-я мужского и общего рода (то есть по первому "школьному слконению). Аналогично склонялись все одушевленные слова на -ко (мужичишко, купчишко, докторишко; включая и украинские фамилии, хотя у них были особенности). Фактически ничто со словами среднего рода их не связывало, кроме орфографического О в конце слова. Это О и было решено упразднить.  Теперь там А - и общий тип склонения.

Иное дело - неодушевленные (армячишко, баянишко...). Они при склонении используют парадигму среднего рода, кроме родительного единиственного, где допустимы обе формы (армячишка и армячишки).

Исключение - "городишко", это слово имеет допустимые вариативные формы во всех падежах единственного числа.

> А полностью можете написать?

И. Воробьишка (ранее - воробьишко), воробьишки
Р. Воробьишки, воробьишек
Д. Воробьишке, воробьишкам
В. Воробьишку, воробьишек
Т. воробьишкой, воробьишками
П. (о) воробьишке, воробьишках

(исправил)

Comment: А полностью можете написать?

Comment: "В. Воробьишки" - разве? Виню кого? - Воробьишку.

Answer (score 1):

***Одушевленные*** существительные с суффиксом **-ИШК-** изменяются по 1-му склонению:  *воробьишк**а** — воробьишк**и** — воробьишк**у**.*

**I.** Форма слова менялась, сравнить: ВОРОБЬИШК**О** (М. Горький).

*Страх приподнял с земли **воробьишку,** он подпрыгнул, замахал крыльями — раз, раз, и — на окне!*

У Горького существительное изменяется **по первому склонению**, только **в начальной** форме имеет окончание **О**.

В **современном** языке начальная форма (И. п) — *ВОРОБЬИШК**А**.*
Но в названии рассказа сохраняется **старая** форма И. п. — *ВОРОБЬИШК**О**.*

**II.** Розенталь: [§ 32. Окончания существительных](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=40#pp40).

8. Существительные с суффиксами ***-ушк-/-юшк-, -ышк-/-ишк-*** в форме именительного падежа единственного числа имеют разные окончания:

1) окончание **-а-** имеют существительные мужского рода, обозначающие **одушевленные** предметы, и существительные женского рода: *дедушк**а**, батюшк**а**, парнишк**а**; матушк**а**, долюшк**а**, мелочишк**а**.*

**III.** Примеры:

Самого же меньшего ― Егорку ― Ксения купала в корыте... и брызги летели из-под него, словно **из-под весеннего воробьишки**, когда тот в самой первой лужице барахтается. [Сергей Залыгин. Комиссия (1976)]

Это воробьиха **воробьишку** кормит. И он тоже захотел есть. Прилетел к воробьихе. [Е. И. Чарушин. Тюпа, Томка и сорока (1946)]

Comment: "В современном языке правильно: воробьишка" - разве?

Comment: Ну да, там - воробьшик**и** в родительном, то есть и винительном - воробьишк**и**. Не воробьишк**а**, как вы предлагаете.

Comment: Из словаря: воробьишка, **-и**. Вы сами себе противоречите: "Страх приподнял с земли воробьишк**у**, ...  В современном языке правильно: воробьишк**а**".

Comment: "Страх поднял с земли воробьишка"???

Comment: Ответ изменен так, чтобы он был Вам понятен. Собственно говоря, весь ответ умещается в первом предложении, всё остальное является дополнительным поясняющим  материалом.

Comment: @Sharon Мне всё понятно, вопрошающему — возможно, нет. Осмелилась лишь подправить Ваш ответ. (Можно ведь откатить, если...)

Comment: Спасибо, Римма, всё прекрасно получилось.

Comment: Благодарю. Мне кажется, что в последнее время на сайте какая-то накаленность образовалась. Ненужная. Она отбивает желание участвовать. Нет?

Comment: @Aer Проверьте, пожалуйста, программное обеспечение. В последнее время я не получаю адресованные мне сообщения. Как в этом вопросе — значок о сообщении на панели отсутствует (прошел 1 час).

Comment: @МаркИз (После предложения переместить дискуссию в чат.) Я бы и рада куда-нибудь переместиться, но сообщения, МНЕ адресованные, НЕ ДОХОДЯТ! Я написала об этом еще вчера модератору _Aer_. Как же ж быть? Сообщения от _Sharon_ я не увидела — обнаружила лишь при целенаправленном поиске.